# Что то с кодировкой на сервлете?

Tags: java

С JSP-формы на сервлет принимаются некоторые данные в данном случае ввожу фамилию "Иванов" которую я записываю в String, в отладчике я вижу что string=ÐÐ²Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð², на странице стоит кодировка UTF-8, смена на windows-1251 ничего не дала, только символы поменялись, но по прежнему неразборчивый текст... Подскажите в чем может быть причина и как это поправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
search=new String(search.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"utf-8");
```

Все решил этим